# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException while connecting to a secure port

Tags: java, ssl, websphere-liberty

I am getting a SSL exception when one of my servers tries to connect to a secure port.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath. java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath. PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath
```

I have set the trust store in jvm.options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/rpp/TrustStore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passw0rd
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
```

In server.xml I have added

```
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="/root/ssl/bmx-zuu.net.jks" password="passw0rd" />
```

Is there any other setting which I have to add?

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @Azim yes it is a self signed certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try defining SSL configuration on Liberty as below. Keystore is defined exactly as defined above but add TrustStore in server.xml. Assumption is that TrustStore.jks has the signer certificates to establish trust with the server.

```
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef=“myTrustStore"/>
        <<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="/root/ssl/bmx-zuu.net.jks" password="passw0rd" />
        <keyStore id=“myTrustStore" location="${server.config.dir}/TrustStore.jks" password="mypassword" type="JKS"/>
```

Comment: Liberty sets it's default SSLContext to the process default SSLContext using SSLContext.setDefault().  So what was set in your jvm.options file will get wiped out.   It's mentioned here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_liberty_ssl_defaults.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<portnumber> -showcerts
```

Look at the output and determine what the subject and issuer of the certificate are.

Verify that the issuer of the certificate is in your TrustStore file.

If this was issued from an intermediate CA, the server should be presenting the issuance chain up to the root of the path (less the root CA). Your trust store should contain the Root CA certificate.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue with the truststore, since this works with Tomcat. I am facing this issue in Liberty

Comment: Is liberty attempting to call out to something on TLS? Setting the trust store like that fit liberty would only allow it to trust certs issued by what is in there

Comment: How do i verify that? Is there any other way to set the trust store?

Comment: Are you expecting the JSSE default truststore to be used, cacerts?  Liberty does not use cacerts.   You can always configure Liberty to point to cacerts file for trust if you want.